# I can't access my website using tomcat

Tags: networking, configuration, webserver, tomcat

I'm trying to create my own website using JSP, Tomcat...

I'm trying to install Tomcat in Ubuntu (in my Cloud Instance) but I can't access my website.

I trying to install Tomcat 9 and I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 x64

I use this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

But on Step 8 when I will access my website http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 nothing happens.
I'm using Chrome to access website so it responds "This page is not working"

So I started to investigate using this code:

> sudo systemctl status tomcat

This is the result of command:

[image: Result of command]

But for me this message is OK.

So I tried to create a server Node.JS to see if the problem is the firewall or port 8080, and it's work, the page loads correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the logs? Hopefully you could find them with `sudo locate catalina`. You could also try deploying the [sample application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/) to the webapps direcory.

Comment: That's it, it's only add something in webapps. Thanks very much.